# localStorage event listener does not fire in Chrome for local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, local-storage

I need to be notified when `localStorage` is changed. This code works fine in Firefox 24, but doesn't work in Chrome 29 (or 30) or in IE 10. It also works on a live server, but not when I am testing using a local file (`file:///`).

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submit').click(function() {
                console.log('Clicked');
                if($('#username').val() != "")
                    localStorage.setItem('someItem', 'someValue');
            });
            $(window).bind('storage', function(e) {
                alert('change');
            });


        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" />
<a href="#" id="submit">Click me</a>
<p id="result"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem with this in Chrome? I'm opening two tabs as required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will only fire the event in the "other" tabs/windows but not in the one changing the data (this is a bit unclear in your question so please correct me if I misunderstood).

> When the setItem(), removeItem(), and clear() methods are called on a
>   Storage object x that is associated with a local storage area, if the
>   methods did something, then in every Document object whose Window
>   object's localStorage attribute's Storage object is associated with
>   the same storage area, **other than x**, a storage event must be fired,
>   as described below.

[Source W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute)

**Update** to complete the answer based on comments:

There will be restrictions in some browsers if the page is running from the file protocol (`file:///`) due to security reasons.

In Chrome you can override this by supplying the argument `--allow-file-access-from-files`:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

I'm not sure if you can do something similar with other browsers. I would recommend testing with a local server (e.g. such as [Mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/)) in order to not run into any surprises in a live scenario.

Comment: I read specification from W3C, I think I understand it, my problem is I open two tab, in tab2, I changed value of localStorage, but tab1 don't have any happen. Did you try on Chrome version 29?

Comment: @TrungHuynh please provide a fiddle that I can test with.

Comment: Here is it! http://jsfiddle.net/4ftxj/ ! But it need two tabs for run completely, because follow specification, it can't listen on tab which change localStorage.

Comment: @TrungHuynh Hm, the test only gave me this error message: `Uncaught SecurityError: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.` probably due to jsfiddle's use of iframe. BTW: Do you test this on a local server or from `file:///` ?

Comment: Yes, I test on file:///. Still don't test on local server. I will do it now and inform soon here, but I think it the same.

Comment: OK, I can run on local server. I don't know why but maybe it's different between local server and file://

Comment: @TrungHuynh yeah, the file protocol is limited by security restrictions (IIRC you can force Chrome to allow file protocol to be used by using `--allow-file-access` as argument. I'm not sure the same is available for Firefox etc.).

Comment: `file://` can run on Firefox without any argument. Just click and run.