# Local Storage event won't fire in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

I am trying to add an event listener that fires whenever data in local storage is changed. I have added the listener in my ComponentDidMount method like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {
    console.log("Event");
    }
  );
```

But the event never seems to fire in Chrome (it fires in Firefox). I have tried it with two tabs, two windows, etc. Am I missing something? I thought that Chrome was able to support local storage functionality.

Comment: [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onstorage) suggests it's a mozilla feature, and MDN don't know if other browsers support it - it's only very recent in mozilla too

Comment: My version of Chrome(51.0.2704.103) triggers the event when changes are made from a separate tab. Can you provide a example demo of it not occurring?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [localStorage event listener cannot fire in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150638/localstorage-event-listener-cannot-fire-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

If you are testing this using local files, Chrome prevents local files (`file:///*`) from "talking" to each other by default as a security measure. You can disable this restriction by launching Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Now the storage event should work as expected with local files.

Answer (score 0):

I was just researching this same problem and found an existing bug in Chrome when document.domain is set via script: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=136356

In this case, localStorage gets set, but the event is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a utility like [localDataStorage](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage) to handle this for you, where events are fired in the same window/tab whenever a key value changes, such as those made by the set or remove methods. You can also use it to transparently set/get any of the following "types": Array, Boolean, Date, Float, Integer, Null, Object or String.

[DISCLAIMER] I am the author of the utility [/DISCLAIMER]

Once you instantiate the utility, the following snippet will allow you to monitor the events:

```
function localStorageChangeEvents( e ) {
    console.log(
        "timestamp: "     + e.detail.timestamp + " (" + new Date( e.detail.timestamp ) + ")" + "\n" +
        "key: "           + e.detail.key     + "\n" +
        "old value: "     + e.detail.oldval  + "\n" +
        "new value: "     + e.detail.newval  + "\n"
    );
};
document.addEventListener(
    "localDataStorage"
    , localStorageChangeEvents
    , false
);
```